# Allow page text to be edited from inside the wordpress menu without hardcoding it

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

New to WordPress theme design, and my google searching is not returning what I am after.

I have a theme I have created and its fine, but the text is all hardcoded into the theme.

I want there to be options in the theme appearance settings? (right place?) where a user can e.g. enter their 'about us' text.

But I have no idea what I should be searching or how to pull in that information into my theme.

Im no a beginner to PHP, but just the way WordPress works itself.

A link, search term or quick start is all I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find the (Free) Advanced Custom Fields plugin useful: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can add unlimited custom fields and create user interfaces for non-technical people to add content to your theme without them touching any code.

If you set up a field named 'about_text', calling it in your theme would look like this:

`<?php the_field('about_text'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should learn how wordpress is working to display the content. In back office, under Settings > Reading you'll find an option that let you tell how you want Wordpress to deal with the front page : is it a listing of the posts, or a static page?

If you choose the first options, it will use the `index.php` template from your theme folder. If it's a static page, you'll have to select which page to use for displaying the home (a page you created under the Menu page). The template that will be use then is `front-page.php`.

For every post / page (page is a `post_type`, just a variation of post) there will be a title field, a wysiwyg content and a featured image which will be displayed in a template. That's all you can manage by default. To display the title you can use [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), the content [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) and for the featured image you will need [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) - note that those functions will need to be used [inside the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

In order to display some more fun, you have many tools at your disposal:

- [Widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes) : widgets are displayed in a sidebar - don't take it literally, it's just a zone of your template. You can register a sidebar with [`register_sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) (use this inside your `functions.php` file, within an [init hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init)). Then in your template you can display the sidebar with [`dynamic_sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar).

  In WP back office, go then under Appearence > Widgets. You will find your brand new sidebar where you can put any kind of widget you want. If you need a wysiwyg widget, I recommend you to install the [Black Studio TinyMCE widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/).
- [Custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) : any `post_type` (a post type is an entry in `wp_posts`) in Wordpress have some associated metas store in `wp_postmeta`. A meta is defined by a key and a value - it's like any post have an associated array that you can customize.

  There is two ways to work with custom fields. First, you can use the default Wordpress feature: when editing a page, click on the screen options button on the top right and enable "custom fields". You will now have a new area to work with on the bottom of the page : you can add fields by name (by default it will list the existing fields names but you can add your own) and value. It's good enough to simple text fields. Then in your template, you can get that value with the [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function.

  The other way is to use a custom fields plugin, which allow you to have wysiwyg fields, loops, media uploader, datepicker... Two popular plugins are [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and [Custom Field Suite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/). They both allow you to easily create set of fields for any page / post_type from the back office, and provide their own functions to manipulate fields in templates (but you can still use the WP functions if you want). For example, to get a custom field with Custom Field Suite you do: `CFS()->get('my_custom_field')`.
- [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) : sometimes, custom fields and widgets are not really convenient when you deal with a lot of data with possibly associated pages. In that cases, you can create your own post types just like posts or pages, but you can define which capabilities they have. Use [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) to define your new post type (still in `init` hook), that will make a new section available in your back office, just like posts. Then in your template you can query them with [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts), the WP function that you will probably the most use when you'll start to play with Wordpress. I suggest you to read the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) documentation in order to learn more about it.

And, at last but not least, you can create your own template that you can associate with any pages. For that, create a php file named whatever you want in your theme folder, paste into it the content from `page.php` and add this PHP comment on top :

```
/*
Template Name: My Template
*/
```

Then choose this template in the dropdown when you edit a page (on the right sidebar).

I think you will have enough to play with, but if you want learn more I recommend you to read about [Wordpress hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) and [the Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) to create your own widgets.

Have fun with Wordpress!